# how to add or cancatenate string in a HTML string in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I have html string which i want to load in web view but i want that there are some values which i am getting as result so i want to add them also in this at run time like

I have   a string belwo i want this value to be added with line 
so that it should display  Number of dogs that visit clinic ? 12 like this

```
 NSString*dogspermonth=12;

 Number of dogs that visit clinic? <br>


 NSString*htmlString=@"<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>JAMSHED ALI</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
<BODY background="InsideBackgroundPage2.png">
<H6><font color="white">Cerenia Motion Sickness<br>
Model</br>Report
<p>Inputs</p>
<br>
 Number of dogs that visit clinic? <br>
 Number of dogs with motion sickness <br>
 Dogs treated with (per year):      <br>

Cerenia <br>                                       
Other prescription drugs<br>
Other means<br>                            
Other the counter drugs<br>  
<p>
Average cost to client for Cerenia prescription<br>      
Clinic markup<br><br>


Average number of dogs treated for car sickness<br>
Total number of dogs treated for car sickness<br>
Dogs treated with Cerenia<br>
Dogs treated with other drugs or interventions<br>

<br>  
  Profit for each Cerenia prescription<br>
  Annual Profit earned from Cerenia treatment<br>
  Potential annual profit increase  from using Cerenia to treat all dogs with motion sickness<br>
 Maximum annual profit if all dogs with car sickness were treated with Cerenia<br>
</BODY>
 </head>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all

```
NSString*dogspermonth=12; //is wrong
NSString *dogspermonth=@"12"; //is correct if u want string else
NSInteger dogspermonth = 12; //will suffice
```

next u can use stringWithFormat like:

```
NSString *htmlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>JAMSHED ALI</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
<BODY background="InsideBackgroundPage2.png">
<H6><font color="white">Cerenia Motion Sickness<br>
Model</br>Report
<p>Inputs</p>
<br>
 Number of dogs that visit clinic? %@<br> //%@ if string //%d if integer
 Number of dogs with motion sickness <br>
 Dogs treated with (per year):      <br>

Cerenia <br>                                       
Other prescription drugs<br>
Other means<br>                            
Other the counter drugs<br>  
<p>
Average cost to client for Cerenia prescription<br>      
Clinic markup<br><br>


Average number of dogs treated for car sickness<br>
Total number of dogs treated for car sickness<br>
Dogs treated with Cerenia<br>
Dogs treated with other drugs or interventions<br>

<br>  
  Profit for each Cerenia prescription<br>
  Annual Profit earned from Cerenia treatment<br>
  Potential annual profit increase  from using Cerenia to treat all dogs with motion sickness<br>
 Maximum annual profit if all dogs with car sickness were treated with Cerenia<br>
</BODY>
 </head>", dogspermonth];
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: it is giving me error when i use this and add the String vari 12

Comment: expected before token in this line

Comment: you will be required to escape the special characters such as \,{} etc using the backslash. The error will be generated because double quotes marks the start and end of a string.

Comment: i don't have any special character you can see in the edited line

Comment: and also try writing everything in one line coz i wrote everything in one line after adding \ (escape character) after " and it worked fine. hope it helps.

Comment: @AnshukGarg infromt of " at the end or start

Comment: <BODY background=\"InsideBackgroundPage2.png\">
<H6><font color=\"white\">Cerenia Motion Sickness<br>

Comment: @AnshukGrag thanks error is removed now but it does not show anything in webView

Comment: gud that this problem is solved. can you plz accept my answer if it helped u. if its not showing, there must be some error in the logic of the code. that ill look into. meanwhile accept my answer to your current prob. thnx :)